# spring-boot-starter-aop around annotated interface's method won't advice my aspect

Tags: aop, aspectj, spring-aop, pointcut

I have the following implementation:

```
public interface BusinessResource {

    @RequiresAuthorization
    public ResponseEnvelope getResource(ParamObj param);
}
```

and

```
@Component
public class BusinessResourceImpl implements BusinessResource {

    @Autowired
    public Response getResource(ParamObj param) {
        return Response.ok().build();
    }
}
```

and

```
import org.aspectj.lang.ProceedingJoinPoint;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Around;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Aspect;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Aspect
@Component
public class AuthorizerAspect {

    protected static final Logger LOGGER =
                      LoggerFactory.getLogger(AuthorizerAspect.class);

    @Autowired
    public AuthorizerAspect() {
        LOGGER.info("Break point works here..." +
        "so spring is creating the aspect as a component...");
    }

    @Around(value="@annotation(annotation)")
    public Object intercept(ProceedingJoinPoint jp,
                            RequiresAuthorization annotation) throws Throwable {
        LOGGER.info("BEGIN");
        jp.proceed();
        LOGGER.info("END");
    }
}
```

The maven dependencies are properly configured with the **spring-boot-starter-aop** dependency. So what happens is that **AuthorizerAspect** won't intercept around the getResource method if the @**RequiresAuthorization** is used on the declared method of the **BusinessResource** interface, but if I change the implementation to annotate the same method now in the **BusinessResourceImpl** class, the aspect will take place.

NOTE: With the annotation in the interface level, the proxy isn't even created, whereas the annotation being placed in the implementation level will create a proxy for the resource.

**Question is: Is there a way to advice objects which the annotation is present just on the interface?**

Answer (score 0):

May this alternative be useful for those who like me found no direct approach to sort that limitation on Spring AOP through proxies:

```
public interface BusinessResource {

    @RequiresAuthorization
    public ResponseEnvelope getResource(ParamObj param);
}
```

And

```
@Component
public class BusinessResourceImpl implements BusinessResource {

    @Autowired
    public Response getResource(ParamObj param) {
        return Response.ok().build();
    }
}
```

And

```
import import org.aopalliance.intercept.MethodInvocation;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

@Configuration
public class AuthorizerAspect {

    protected static final Logger LOGGER =
                      LoggerFactory.getLogger(AuthorizerAspect.class);

    @Autowired
    public AuthorizerAspect() {
        LOGGER.info("Break point works here..." +
        "so spring is creating the aspect as a component...");
    }

    public Object invoke(MethodInvocation invocation) throws Throwable {
        LOGGER.info("BEGIN");
        invocation.proceed();
        LOGGER.info("END");
    }

    @Bean
    public DefaultAdvisorAutoProxyCreator defaultAdvisorAutoProxyCreator() {
        return new DefaultAdvisorAutoProxyCreator();
    }

    @Bean("requiresAuthorizationPointcut")
    public AbstractPointcutAdvisor createPointcut() {
        return new AbstractPointcutAdvisor() {

            private static final long serialVersionUID = 4733447191475535406L;

            @Override
            public Advice getAdvice() {
                return AuthorizerAspect.this;
            }

            @Override
            public Pointcut getPointcut() {
                return  new StaticMethodMatcherPointcut() {
                    @Override
                    public boolean matches(Method method, Class<?> targetClass) {
                        if (method.isAnnotationPresent(RequiresAuthorization.class)) {
                            return true;
                        }
                        if (method.getDeclaringClass().isInterface()) {
                            String methodName = method.getName();
                            try {
                                Method targetMethod = targetClass.getMethod(methodName, method.getParameterTypes());
                                return targetMethod != null && targetMethod.isAnnotationPresent(RequiresAuthorization.class);
                            } catch (NoSuchMethodException |
                                     SecurityException e) {
                                LOGGER.debug("FAILURE LOG HERE",
                                             e.getMessage());
                                return false;
                            }
                        }
                        return method.isAnnotationPresent(RequiresAuthorization.class);
                    }
                };
            }
        };
    }
}
```

So as you'll notice, we're sorting it by using method interceptors.

Comment: please be sure there's no problem before committing your answer. where is invoke method return? and where package of Advice class is?